# Transform a list of lists into a differently arranged list of lists to use for pmap

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, pmap

I've been struggling really hard to get `pmap()` to work and misunderstood the structure of the list that I am supposed to feed it.

Basically, I ended up with a list of lists, `before`, but it's not in the correct arrangement for pmap.

Here's a minimum repro of what it's like:

```
before <- list(
  list(
    tibble(a = c(10:13), b = c(13:16), c = c(17:20)),
    tibble(d = c(10:13), e = c(13:16)),
    tibble(f = c(10:13))
  ),
  list(
    tibble(a = c(10:13), b = c(13:16), c = c(17:20)),
    tibble(d = c(21:24), e = c(25:28)),
    tibble(f = c(21:24))
  ),
  list(
    tibble(a = c(31:34), b = c(35:38), c = c(20:23)),
    tibble(d = c(31:34), e = c(35:38)),
    tibble(f = c(31:34))
  ),
  list(
    tibble(a = c(40:43), b = c(43:46), c = c(47:50)),
    tibble(d = c(40:43), e = c(43:46)),
    tibble(f = c(40:43))
  )
)
```

However, that's wrong for what to use as the `.l` argument in `pmap()`.

I think would like to transform it into a list of lists like below, `after`.

```
after <- list(
  list(
    tibble(a = c(10:13), b = c(13:16), c = c(17:20)),
    tibble(a = c(10:13), b = c(13:16), c = c(17:20)),
    tibble(a = c(31:34), b = c(35:38), c = c(20:23)),
    tibble(a = c(40:43), b = c(43:46), c = c(47:50))
  ),
  list(
    tibble(d = c(10:13), e = c(13:16)),
    tibble(d = c(21:24), e = c(25:28)),
    tibble(d = c(31:34), e = c(35:38)),
    tibble(d = c(40:43), e = c(43:46))
  ),
  list(
    tibble(f = c(10:13)),
    tibble(f = c(21:24)),
    tibble(f = c(31:34)),
    tibble(f = c(40:43))
  )
)
```

That way, I could perform this...

```
x <- pmap(after, my_func)
```

Where `my_func` is a function that takes 3 different tibbles as arguments. It's actually a function that creates complicated ggplots.

The questions are:

- How can I transform `before` to `after`?
- Is `after` in the right form to use `pmap` to map to a function that takes 3 tibbles as arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tranpose` from purrr:

```
library(purrr)

after2 <- tranpose(before)

identical(after, after2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple, but I just didn't see it!

Answer (score 2):

Using *lapply*:

```
out <- lapply(1:3, \(i) lapply(before, "[[", i))

#check
identical(out, after)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

With `pmap` use arguments that fit the list content

```
before %>% purrr::pmap(\(x, y, z, k) list(x, y, z, k))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
# A tibble: 4 × 3
      a     b     c
  <int> <int> <int>
1    10    13    17
2    11    14    18
3    12    15    19
4    13    16    20

[[1]][[2]]
# A tibble: 4 × 3
      a     b     c
  <int> <int> <int>
1    10    13    17
2    11    14    18
3    12    15    19
4    13    16    20
...
```

Test on `after`

```
identical(after, before %>% purrr::pmap(\(x, y, z, k) list(x, y, z, k)))
[1] TRUE
```